# Мессенджер на Java

Tags: java

Стоит задача написать мессенджер сообщений на Java.

Функционал:

1. Регистрация/авторизация в сервисе.
2. Обмен сообщениями точка-точка, точка-многоточка.
3. Подписка на определенные темы и рассылка всем кто подписан на темы.
4. Сообщения должны храниться на сервере и должна использоваться отложенная доставка.
5. Чтобы всё это работало быстро. :D

Собственно стоит вопрос как реализовывать клиент-серверное взаимодействие, из вариантов вижу:

1. Писать свой протокол, на основе сокетов. (java.io / java.nio)
2. Использовать RMI (java.rmi)
3. Использовать как часть системы JMS (какой-нибудь Active MQ)
4. JAX-RPC / JAX-WS
5. etc ?

Собственно, хотелось бы услышать рекомендации, что лучше использовать для данного проекта + какие фреймворки лучше использовать: Spring (IoC, Remoting), Netty , etc...

Comment: лично мне это напоминает "из пушки по воробьям"...

1) я б использовал обмен данными в формате `json` по `http` протоколу
2) задача сервера - авторизация и генерация сообщений для конкретного клианта (из полученных от других пользователей и сгенерированых на основе подписки на темы) 
3) задача клиента - опрашивать сервер раз в Х секунд/минут (в зависимости от необходимой скорости доставки), также клиент должен иметь возможность накапливать сообщения и при опросе сервера отправлять сообщения на сервер.

Comment: Так же возможно понадобиться, организация "сообщений о присутствии", чтобы показывать статус клиента, но это уже позже.

Понимаю, что "из пушки по воробьям", но хочется использовать правильные вещи, и по возможности не писать то что уже где-то когда-то кем-то реализовано.

Comment: > и по возможности не писать то что уже где-то когда-то кем-то реализовано.

из перечисленных вами технологий вам нужен только (4), все остальное архитектуру не упростит. предлагаемый стек технологий:

`json, http, rest ws, netty, cdi, ejb,` + какая-то `nosql db` (для накопления сообщений)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас небольшой туман в голове вы путаете божий дар с яишницей ))

1. RMI это вариант IPC протокола обмена между двумя инстансами JVM размещенных на разных машинах
2. JMS это серверная технология асинхронной доставки сообщений между различными потребителями - в качестве протокола доставки может использоваться более-менее любой протокол - в общем случае зависит от провайдера JMS.
3. JAX-RPC - это Java реализация XML/WSDL протокола обмена IPC. В силу своей природы он не требует наличия JVM на одной из сторон и в принципе может использоваться в любых осях (при наличии реализации WSDL на клиенте)

Вам нужно определиться с протоколом доставки от клиента к серверу и обратно и собственно как в сервере обрабатывать эти сообщения. Для этого надо понимать как и на чем будет работать клиент. Если клиент всегда Java - то это один вариант, а если допускается что клиент не всегда c Java (читай с JVM) - то это уже другая история.

Я бы лично остановился на JMS с JSON протоколом (ActiveMQ по моему поддерживает JSON). WSDL имеет слишком большой оверхед и уже не моден сейчас :)

Comment: Предполагается что клиент и сервер будут написаны на java.
Получается, что при варианте JMS+JSON нужно отдельно поднимать JMS и отдельно поднимать HTTP и уже поверх него передавать по JSON? Довольно сложная система получается...

Comment: Ну чуток на будущее тоже стоит заложиться, вдруг клиент не на java будет. Я бы не стал RMI использовать

Comment: @lightcyber JMS вообще тяжелая штука - я бы сказал очень тяжелая и сложная штука. Посмотрите на эту [презентацию](http://www.slideshare.net/bruce.snyder/messaging-with-activemq-presentation)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы при такой задаче постарался заюзать существующий протокол, например XMPP. Чтобы не изобретать велосипед.
Но если надо было бы всё своё и побыстрее, то я бы сервер запилил с использованием Jetty, а сам протокол на основе http сделал бы

Comment: XMPP нормальный вариант, есть и сервера и клиенты и API все чего хошь есть - поддерживаю.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону: [AcitveMQ, STOMP Over WebSockets](http://sensatic.net/activemq/activemq-54-stomp-over-web-sockets.html)

Comment: Спасибо.

Нашел несколько реализаций на Java:

http://www.germane-software.com/software/Java/Gozirra/

http://mrstampy.github.io/Stampy/

http://code.google.com/p/stompj/downloads/list

https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms